# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

It has been a while since I've worked with React-Router and the first time with v6. My applications is using:

- Vite
- React
- Material-UI

I've attempted the following:

- Searched the web
- reread the docs multiple times
- followed the `react-router` tutorial and applied it to my application

I've been taking a step by step approach to the application where I test each change before I go onto the next. It appears my routing is correct as I tested it by typing in the routes as the URL. However, when I attempt to add `Link`, I'm getting the out of context error.  I know I'm missing something simple but I'm just not seeing it. Here is the code with imports omitted for brevity.

index.jsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
      <CssBaseline />
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

app.jsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: "",
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Products />,
      },
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
    ]
  },

]);

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (  
    <><HeaderBar />
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <div>
        <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    </RouterProvider></>
  )
}

export default App
```

HeaderBar.jsx (only failing element is shown for brevity)

```
<Button
  key={page.text}
  onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
  sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
  component={Link}
  to={page.target}
>
  {page.text}
</Button>
```

I have attempted to create the context by trying to wrap `<BrowserRouter>` around various components, but receive error messages about having 2 routers in my application.

Comment: Simply put, your `<HeaderBar>` is outside the `<RouterProvider>` so `<Link>` will fail. Move it inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `HeaderBar` is rendered *outside* a router, e.g. any routing context, so the `Link` component doesn't work. Move it into the router.

The `RouterProvider` component also doesn't consume any `children` prop, so the "child" JSX is completely ignored and should be removed.

Example using a layout route component to render the header and `Outlet` for the nested routes:

```
const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <HeaderBar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <AppLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Products />,
      },
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
    ]
  },

]);

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```